# Sometimes the spreadsheet has the left side columns cut off, and you can't scroll to them

Tags: excel, excel-2010, office-interop

I'm using Excel COM Interop to automate creating spreadsheets, and sometimes the left side (columns A-H) of the spreadsheet is not visible and I can't scroll to the left. Columns B-E are intentionally hidden and there's a freeze pane at P4. This problem is inconsistent, it happens for only a few people, and doesn't happen every time.

Edit: 
The shift happens right after applying the freeze panes. Here's the snippet of code that adds the freeze pane.

```
inout Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
worksheet.Activate();
worksheet.Range[GetEditableArea()].Select();
worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
```

and here's GetEditableArea()

```
function returns string ColumnRow;
ColumnRow = ColNumToString(COLUMN_OFFSET + 1) + str(ROW_OFFSET + 1);
```

COLUMN_OFFSET = 15 (the columns after this are dynamic)
ROW_OFFSET = 3

I put dialog messages before each statement, and then watched the Excel spreadsheet getting created. The shift to the right is happening right after **worksheet.Range[GetEditableArea()].Select();**

Comment: Is it possible that cols A-H are scrolled out of view before the 'freeze panes' is applied?  This would prevent scrolling to them. Presumably you can scroll to them before 'freeze panes' is applied? How/when is 'freeze panes' applied?

Comment: All of the formatting is done after all the data is exported. It's done in this order: freeze panes, autofit columns, hide columns, unlock editable areas, and then protect the sheet. If i show the spreadsheet while it's being created i can see it shift to the right (causing the problem) while formatting is being done.

Comment: Where in this sequence does the sheet shift right and is this reproducible e.g. with same data? Can you share your code?

Comment: After putting some debugging messages in there I can see that it is shifting to the right right after applying freeze panes. 

Note: I edited the the original post with the code snippet

Comment: Your comment doesn't match what you say in your post edit.  However, can you post your code for GetEditableArea()

Comment: Sorry about that, i'll clarify. I had a debugging message before the call to that function, and then when i posted the code snippet i put debugging messages after each statement in the function. And as requested i put the GetEditableArea() and the constants used in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find `Window.Split` rather than Freeze Panes to be more versatile for your requirement.  More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834706(v=office.15).aspx) (VBA) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f01c683d-159d-4d18-b54c-7fad86207f17/split-bar-in-excel-sheet-using-vbnet) (vb.net)

If you persevere with Freeze Panes then clearly in use, to be of any use, your freeze point needs to be visible within the active window.  If it isn't (which may be the case in your example depending on what ColumnRow returns) then the `Select` action will move it to centre window.  You could use `Application.Goto Range(?)` which would set it as rightmost as it can.  This may help.  The issue would appear to be arranging for your required rows to be visible given the freeze point in any given situation.

Before you set Freeze Panes you could use some of the following:

`ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn` to more finely tweak overall column positions

`ActiveWindow.Zoom` to reduce the zoom level to get more columns into view to accommodate the freeze point

`ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized` to maximise the window area to get more columns into view

Reduce column widths (`Columns.AutoFit`?) or `Hide` more columns to get the required columns into view

Rearrange the columns in your model (temporarily or otherwise) to get the required columns into view

Comment: I put ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized right before .Select() and it took care of the problem! I tested with additional dynamic columns, which means more columns to the right, and verified that it worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I did research and troubleshoot this issue with some computers and found that, It happens random, only to computers with slow resolution.. and only those with excel 2016, excel 2013 reported no issue in all computers.

What i did to fix this issue:

1. select all rows and columns
2. hide all columns
3. unhide all columns

This fixed my issue, no code change at all..

Now because i know this fix the issue i will add this steps in my code!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with a report and resolved it successfully, using Edwin Blancovitch's solution above, by hiding several of the left hand columns before freezing the panes and then unhiding them immediate after:

```
    'Set pane freeze
    'v.1.1.000 Added hide and unhide of columns A - F to correct problem where left handed columns
    '          were not displaying when Donor Comments Modified spreadsheet opened. 09 May 21 sjl
    .Columns("A:F").Hidden = True
    .Range("H2").Select
    xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    .Columns("A:F").Hidden = False
```

I also tried "ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized". While this also worked, it prevented the access vba code from closing the Excel Application, even though I closed the application and set it to nothing afterward. So I could not use that solution.